# Google Slides: how to change the 'Theme' colors

Tags: presentation-design, google

Does anyone know how to change the theme colors in Google slides? I don't mean the 'Custom' colors, but rather, the 'Theme' colors? I can't seem to figure this out. I have to create a corporate slide master template with Google SLides, and I'd like to set the Theme colors so that they match up with the brand palette.

[image: Color window in Google slides showing 'Theme' colors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really late reply, but the solution I found, was to export your slides to Powerpoint, set the theme colors there, and then re-upload your PPTX file to Google Slides. It picks up the color theme as set on Powerpoint.